# Increasing the visibility of a view on Swipe using Gestures in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-animation

I am using following code

```
private GestureDetector.OnGestureListener mGestureListener = new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener()
{
    private float lastDeltaValue;
    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 15;
    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE_Y = 25;
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        lastDeltaValue = 0;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
        float startingX = (int)e1.getRawX();
        float startingY = (int)e1.getRawY();

        float endingX = (int)e2.getRawX();
        float endingY = (int)e2.getRawY();

        float deltaX = startingX - endingX;
        float deltaY = startingY - endingY;

        // swipe horizontal?
        if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(deltaY) < MIN_DISTANCE_Y)
        {
            // left or right
            if(deltaX > 0)
            {
                shouldCallBtn = SHOULD_CALL_WHERE;
                if (gestureLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    gestureLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    gestureLayout.setAlpha(0.3f);
                }
                gestureText.setText(getString(R.string.option_where));
                if (deltaX > lastDeltaValue)
                {
                    if (gestureLayout.getAlpha() > 0.29 && gestureLayout.getAlpha() < 0.80)
                        gestureLayout.setAlpha(gestureLayout.getAlpha() + 0.1f);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (gestureLayout.getAlpha() < 0.81 && gestureLayout.getAlpha() > 0.29)
                        gestureLayout.setAlpha(gestureLayout.getAlpha() - 0.1f);
                }
                Log.d("DELTA VALUES", String.valueOf(deltaX) + "  ==  " + String.valueOf(lastDeltaValue) + "   " +String.valueOf(gestureLayout.getAlpha()));

                lastDeltaValue = deltaX;

            }
            else if(deltaX < 0)
            {
                shouldCallBtn = SHOULD_CALL_ONMYWAY;
                if (gestureLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    gestureLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    gestureLayout.setAlpha(0.3f);
                }
                gestureText.setText(getString(R.string.option_onway));
                if (deltaX > lastDeltaValue)
                {
                    if (gestureLayout.getAlpha() > 0.29 && gestureLayout.getAlpha() < 0.80)
                        gestureLayout.setAlpha(gestureLayout.getAlpha() - 0.1f);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (gestureLayout.getAlpha() < 0.81 && gestureLayout.getAlpha() > 0.29)
                        gestureLayout.setAlpha(gestureLayout.getAlpha() + 0.1f);
                }
                Log.d("DELTA VALUES", String.valueOf(deltaX) + "  ==  " + String.valueOf(lastDeltaValue) + "   " +String.valueOf(gestureLayout.getAlpha()));

                lastDeltaValue = deltaX;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
        gestureLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gestureLayout.setAlpha(0.8f);
        gestureText.setText(getString(R.string.option_my_location));
        sendLocBtn.performClick();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Initially `GestureLayout` Visibility is `GONE`. After swipe its visibility will increase from 0.3 to 0.8. If i try to left swipe it Increases the alpha of a `View` somewhere on screen with some Text like (Left Swiping) and so does on right swipe.

This code seems to work but the animation of alpha from low to high is not up to standard.

Any help would be helpful

NOTE: I Do not need an animation. I want it to be based on swipe of finger

Comment: Hi Muhammad. When I try to run your code, the following symbols are undefined: `R.string.option_my_location`, `R.string.option_onway`, `R.string.option_where`, `SHOULD_CALL_ONMYWAY`, `SHOULD_CALL_WHERE`, `gestureLayout`,  `gestureText`, `sendLocBtn` and `shouldCallBtn`. Can you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? It will then be possible to easily reproduce the problem you are having, making it much easier to provide a good answer for you.

Comment: @MartinNordholts just replace those with anything or comment them out. Make one view gestureLayout that is important to increase or decrease its visibility

Comment: "This code seems to work but the animation of alpha from low to high is not up to standard." What's the problem?
You want the alpha to be animated while the swipe is in progress?

Comment: i want the alpha to increase smoothly as i swipe the finger right now above code shows weird pattern

Comment: you are setting alpha on a view? i thought it took `int` or im wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets call the value of `0.1f` `deltaAlpha`. `deltaAlpha` must be based on the `deltaX` value. 
You must define a coefficient for your application that is the ratio between the `deltaX` and `deltaAlpha`.
For example lets say that `10px` are equal to `0.01` alpha change. Now you know that if your finger travels `40px` on the screen, the alpha value will
be changed with `0.04` no mater of the speed of the gesture. This way the animation will be smooth and will be based on the distance the finger has moved on the screen. Try the following java code:

```
// 1 deltaX = 0.01 alpha
// This is just an example coefficient.
// Replace it with a value that fits your needs
private static final float COEFFICIENT = 0.01;

private float calculateDeltaAlpha(float deltaX) {
  return deltaX * COEFICIENT;
}

private void incrementViewAlpha(View view, float distanceX) {
  float oldAlpha = gestureLayout.getAlpha();
  if (oldAlpha > 0.29 && oldAlpha < 0.80) {
    gestureLayout.setAlpha(oldAlpha + calculateAlphaDelta(distanceX));
  }
}

private void decrementViewAlpha(View view, float distanceX) {
  float oldAlpha = gestureLayout.getAlpha();
  if (oldAlpha > 0.29 && oldAlpha < 0.80) {
    gestureLayout.setAlpha(oldAlpha - calculateAlphaDelta(distanceX));
  }
}
```

Call `incrementViewAlpha` and `decrementViewAlpha` methods when you want to increase or decrease view's alpha value.

Comment: Agree with Kiril as the alpha variation should proportionately change with the finger movement to achieve a smooth effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have improved over Kiril's code and avoided unnecessary code. You need to modify the COEFFICIENT value to control the variation/smoothness depending on layout size, screen size, related parameters, etc. Let me know if it works for you. Also made changes to limit alpha to be within UPPER_BOUND_ALPHA & LOWER_BOUND_ALPHA.

```
private static final float COEFFICIENT = 0.0001f;
private static final float UPPER_BOUND_ALPHA = 0.8f;
private static final float LOWER_BOUND_ALPHA = 0.3f;

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
{
    float startingX = (int)e1.getRawX();
    float startingY = (int)e1.getRawY();

    float endingX = (int)e2.getRawX();
    float endingY = (int)e2.getRawY();

    float deltaX = startingX - endingX;
    float deltaY = startingY - endingY;

    // swipe horizontal?
    if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(deltaY) < MIN_DISTANCE_Y) 
    {
        if (gestureLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) 
        {
            gestureLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            gestureLayout.setAlpha(LOWER_BOUND_ALPHA);
        }

        // left or right
        if(deltaX > 0)
        {
            shouldCallBtn = SHOULD_CALL_WHERE;
            gestureText.setText(getString(R.string.option_where));
        }
        else if(deltaX < 0)
        {
            shouldCallBtn = SHOULD_CALL_ONMYWAY;
            gestureText.setText(getString(R.string.option_onway));
        }

        float alphaValue = gestureLayout.getAlpha() + COEFFICIENT * deltaX;
        if (alphaValue > UPPER_BOUND_ALPHA) 
        {
            alphaValue = UPPER_BOUND_ALPHA;
        } 
        else if (alphaValue < LOWER_BOUND_ALPHA) 
        {
            alphaValue = LOWER_BOUND_ALPHA;
        }

        gestureLayout.setAlpha(alphaValue);

        Log.d("DELTA VALUES", deltaX + "  ==  " + lastDeltaValue + "   " + gestureLayout.getAlpha());
        lastDeltaValue = deltaX;
    }

    return false;
}
```